# I want to find unique duplicates value in array,but i am not getting below is my code in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
`
import java.util.Scanner;
public class duplicateValue {
    public static void reverse(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            {
         for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
             if((a[i]==a[j]))
             {
                 System.out.println(a[i]+" is duplicated");

             }
            }
             
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the size of array");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the "+n+"no. of elements");
    int[] a=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    reverse(a);
}
}`
```

My sample input is : 1 2 2 2 3
I am getting output like
2 is duplicated
2 is duplicated
2 is duplicated

I need unique duplicate outupt how to do it.

Comment: Try using a `Set`.

Comment: Is it not possible to get it by modifications in this code

Comment: It is, but it would be very inefficient.

Comment: Then Can  u please suggest how to do this in above code...

Comment: The only way I can think of is to make an extra array and for each duplicate that you find, add it to that array if the array doesn't already contain it (no duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list,

then check if the list contains the duplicate

if not
add a duplicate to the list if present

print list of duplicates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class duplicateValue {
    public static void reverse(int[] a)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int element : a) 
        {   
            if(map.get(element) == null)
            {
                map.put(element, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(element, map.get(element)+1);
            }
        }
        Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
            
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : entrySet) 
        {               
            if(entry.getValue() > 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Element : "+entry.getKey()+" - found "+entry.getValue()+" times.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the size of array");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the "+n+"no. of elements");
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        reverse(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).